# The horizontal scrollbar on my asp.net panel won't scroll

Tags: asp.net, css, scrollbar

I have a repeater wrapped inside a panel (using MVC Asp.net). The scroll bar appears, but my table seems to be wrapping to accomodate the horizontal size of the panel rather than overflowing past the panel.

The scrollbar is showing up, but it doesn't do anything.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMultipleBeneficiaries" ScrollBars = "Horizontal" style="overflow:scroll" runat=""server" >
<div class="section" >
       <fieldset>
        <legend class="labels">Added Beneficiaries</legend>

            <asp:Repeater ID="rptMultipleBeneficiaryDetails" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table border = 1> 
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">First Name</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Last Name</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Status</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Birthday</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Parent</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Street</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">City</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Province</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Postcode</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Country</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Phone Number</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">HasReplied</td>
                        <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Something Else</td>

                    </tr>                   
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BeneficiaryFirstName")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BeneficiaryLastName")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BeneficiarySin")%></td>
                        <td><%#DateTime.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BeneficiaryBirthday").ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Parent")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Street1")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProvinceAbbreviation")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Postcode")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CountryDescription")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HasReplied")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsGrantApplicationFormReceived")%></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>         
        </fieldset>
            </div>
   </asp:Panel>
```

I did try to use style="overflow:auto" in the panel but it doesn't do anything. Help?

Comment: try `style="overfllow:scroll"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the width of the panel. So first set the width of the panel and then assign `overflow:scroll` property to them.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMultipleBeneficiaries" ScrollBars = "Horizontal" style="overflow:scroll" runat="server" Width="500px">
```

one more thing you can try that you can fix the width of `<div class="section">` and set `overflow` property in this class

```
.section
{
 width:500px;
 overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Basically the point is `overflow` property will work when you are having fix width of the `parent` and having `overflow` property with them.

Comment: Ok that makes sense - so then I can set overflow-x and overflow-y in the class? I tried that directly like: style="overflow-y" and it wasn't recognized

Comment: same condition for `overflow:y`. Just set the height in this class as we have set the width and then write `overflow-y:auto`. it will work :)

Comment: Ok... hey, what's the netiquette (or stack overflow standard) for asking related questions?

Answer (score 0):

Sis, Just change the `overflow:auto;`  to `overflow:scroll;`

Comment: I have to do that and size the table accordingly in the panel which worked. PS I'm female...

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me (Browser -> Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)) as well as Internet Explorer 11 Version 11.0.9600.18697

Used for Kendo Grid, both are working.

CSS code:

```
.k-grid-content {
    overflow: scroll;
}

.k-grid-content {
    overflow: auto;
}
```